# Selling an adapted freely aquiered ebook

Tags: epub

As we know many ebooks are free of charge. Those are especially old books that authors died 100 years ago or so. Downloading such an e-book without paying is legal and many people do so.

Given I use content of such an ebook that lost copyrights because of years gone since authors passed away, is it legal to sell digital version of the book adapted with my own pictures and photos?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, so I can't really answer you (and I advise you to seek the advice of a professional with anything regarding laws), but I'm prone to think that selling something that is already free, is not the most profitable business.

Comment: In what way is "your" book an adaptation? How do your own photos add anything? Do you think your photographs of Dublin will enhance Joyce's public domain text *Dubliners?* Please don't do it. Amazon has enough crap public domain editions as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what jurisdiction you're in: almost certainly yes. The entire point of a work being in the "public domain", which is what works that are no longer copyrighted are, is that such works can be reused, remixed, repurposed, and even resold however you you. It's exactly the same legal approach that lets Disney sell copies of its own version of the public-domain story of Snow White.